# How to check that object is instance of generic in Haxe

Tags: generics, casting, haxe

I'm looking for a safe way to fork logic depending on the object type. I haven't found out how to check if an object belongs to a specific generic type.

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var aa = new AA<Int>();
        //ERROR: Cast type parameters must be Dynamic
        //var a:A<Int> = cast(aa, A<Int>); 

        //ERROR: Unexpected )
        //var a:A<Int> = Std.instance(aa, A<Int>);

        //OK, but throw run-time exception with flash target. 
        var a:A<Int> = cast aa; 
        a.printName();

        //Run-time exception
        a = cast "String is obviously wrong type";
    }
}

class A<T> {
    public function new () { }
    public function printName() {
        trace("Generic name: A");
    }
}

class AA<T> extends A<T> {
    public function new () { super(); }
    override public function printName() {
        trace("Generic name AA");
    }
}
```

Is there a legal way to check if an object belongs to a generic type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is generally no great way of doing this, because the information is not available at runtime anymore. You could use the same workaround that is [often suggested for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403987/2631715), which is storing the generic type in your class:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        var a = new A<Int>(Int);

        trace(a.typeParamIs(Int)); // true
        trace(a.typeParamIs(Bool)); // false
    }
}

class A<T> {
    var type:Any;

    public function new (type:Any) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public function typeParamIs(type:Any):Bool {
        return this.type == type;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Type.typeOf()`](http://api.haxe.org/Type.html#typeof) like this if `A` has a field of type `T`:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        checkType(new A<Int>(5)); // Int
        checkType(new A<Bool>(true)); // Bool
        checkType(new A<B>(new B())); // B
        checkType(new A<B>(null)); // unhandled type TNull
    }

    static function checkType<T>(a:A<T>) {
        trace(switch (Type.typeof(a.value)) {
            case TInt: "Int";
            case TBool: "Bool";
            case TClass(cls) if (cls == B): "B";
            case other: throw "unhandled type " + other;
        });
    }
}

class A<T> {
    public var value:T;
    public function new (value:T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class B {
    public function new() {}
}
```

As you can see, while this usually works, it might lead to unexpected behavior in some cases - such as when `value` is `null`. Also keep in mind the docs of `Type.typeOf()`:

> May vary per platform. Assumptions regarding this should be minimized to avoid surprises.

---

Further reading: [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxelang/bTme-k9tvls/FKXR9Ngtu-EJ) where this has been discussed a while back. A macro solution is mentioned there, in case you do *not* need to know the type at runtime.